# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_jobs' and n_clusters

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

hi i got this error while writing this code

```
SSE = []
for cluster in range(1,20):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_jobs = -1, n_clusters = cluster, init='k-means++')
    kmeans.fit(data_scaled)
    SSE.append(kmeans.inertia_)
```

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_jobs'
```

it also happen with n_clusters

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: How do you import KMeans?

Answer (score 0):

When you initialized the KMeans class with `kmeans = KMeans(n_jobs = -1, n_clusters = cluster, init='k-means++')`, the KMeans class did not have n_jobs when it initialized. Look up the class to see what arguments it has in its `def __init__()` function. This error means that the argument n_jobs was not a parameter when KMeans was initialized.

Comment: i omitted n_jobs and worked fine thnaks

Comment: @LO'AY if this answered your Question, please mark it as the Answer with the check to its left to earn reputation and help the community!

Answer (score 0):

`KMeans` doesn't accept `n_jobs` as an argument, you may be able to just omit it (what do you expect `n_jobs=-1` to do for you?)

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: yeah i tried to omit n_jobs but there was issue with n_cluster i thought it was the same issue but it was issue with defining n_cluster in my code

Answer (score 0):

The `n_jobs` parameter was removed from `KMeans` in version [0.23](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_0_23_0.html#scalability-and-stability-improvements-to-kmeans). (I believe it's not possible to use n_jobs for other sklearn algorithms either.)

If you still need parallelism, please use [joblib](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/computing/parallelism.html#higher-level-parallelism-with-joblib):

```
from joblib import parallel_backend

with parallel_backend('threading', n_jobs=2):
    # Your scikit-learn code here
```